# How to initialize session in symfony controllers and access it in views

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I am using symfony 2.7 and I would like to show site navbars like login/logout depending a condition.

I am not using a database to log in users, but rather a session that is enitialized in a controller.

Anyway, how can I tie this session and make sure users see login/logout pages?

Let's say this is a nav

```
<a href='{{ path('login') }}'> login </a>
<a href='{{ path('logout') }}'> logout </a>
```

And this is my controller

```
public function checkSessionAction(Request $request){
    $session = $request->getSession(); 

    if ( some logic ){
        $session->set('user_ID', $someData);
    }
}
```

Now, in simple terms I need a way to see if user_ID is set in twig so to show which nav link I want

Comment: You aren't using a DB? What are you authorizing them with?

Comment: I am learning symfony and I am not quit at the DB part yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your comment, you could use Symfony2 authentication trying something like that:

Use the namespace: UsernamePasswordToken in your controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
```

Retrieve your roles from database and store it in  $aRoleNameToken

```
 $aRoleNameToken = array('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER');
```

Set token if authentication was successful:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($username, null,'secured_area',$aRoleNameToken);

$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

In the view, you could check if that rol has been assigned to the current user:
(http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html)

```
 {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
         <a href="...">Delete</a>
 {% endif %}
```

Log out action:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
 */
public function logoutAction() {
   $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
   $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
   return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('login'));
}
```

In security.yml file, you could do some configurations about the session.

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }   
    - { path: ^/home, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER] } 
    - { path: ^/login, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER]}
    - { path: /, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER]}
```

As you can see ^/login has the value 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY', it means that the login page is the only one that you could see without authentication, if you try to acces to another path for example '/home' or '/admin' and you don't have autenticathion(that was previously setted in your login action), you will be redirected to login page.

```
   - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

For example the next sentence means that you must have the role ROLE_ADMIN, if you want to access to the path: /admin

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the login was successful, you could initialize the session in the controller

`$this->get('session')->set('IsAuth', true);`

In the view using template engine Twig you could check session value:

```
  {% if app.session.get('IsAuth')  %}
         <a href='{{ path('login') }}'> login </a>
   {% else %}
         <a href='{{ path('logout') }}'> logout </a>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw in other examples that we can use ROLE access including modifying the security in the YAML, could you add more example if you have? I know this is the answer I asked, but it looks hacky-ish :)